Qlikview to DAX expression conversion
We have been informed our Qlikview is ending at our company, so looking at moving over to PowerBI.
I am trying to migrate this expression from Qlikview into PowerBI.
My qlikview expression is:
If(SType = 'AA',
only({\<S_type={'AA'}\>} MeanValue)
,
If(SType = 'BB',
only({\<S_type={'BB'}\>} MeanValue)
,
If(SType = 'CC',
only({\<S_type={'CC'}\>} MeanValue)
,
only({\<S_type={'DD'}\>} MeanValue)
)
)
)

SType is in Table1
s_type is in Table 2
MeanValue is stored in Table 2 like:



S_type
MeanValue




AA
2.16


BB
2.30


CC
2.19


DD
2.54



best code I came up with is:
If( CALCULATE(Count('Table1'[SType]), FILTER('Table1', 'Table1'[Type] = "AA")) = 1,
    CALCULATE(SUM('Table2'[MeanValue]), FILTER('Table2', 'Table2'[S_Type] = "AA")),

If( CALCULATE(Count('Table1'[SType]), FILTER('Table1', 'Table1'[Type] = "BB")) = 1,
    CALCULATE(SUM('Table2'[MeanValue]), FILTER('Table2', 'Table2'[S_Type] = "BB")),

If( CALCULATE(Count('Table1'[SType]), FILTER('Table1', 'Table1'[SType] = "CC")) = 1,
    CALCULATE(SUM('Table2'[MeanValue]), FILTER('Table2', 'Table2'[S_Type] = "CC")),

If( CALCULATE(Count('Table1'[SType]), FILTER('Table1', 'Table1'[SType] = "DD")) = 1,
    CALCULATE(SUM('Table2'[MeanValue]), FILTER('Table2', 'Table2'[S_Type] = "DD")))
)
)
)

Is this the best method or is there a alternative more efficient method?

I assume you've heard of ChatGPT, which can probably do this in about 15 seconds?

You need to use SELECTEDVALUE() to get the selected SType in Table1 and avoid  repeated CALCULATE and FILTER :
CalculatedMeanValue = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE,
    SELECTEDVALUE('Table1'[SType]) = "AA", CALCULATE(SUM('Table2'[MeanValue]), 'Table2'[S_type] = "AA"),
    SELECTEDVALUE('Table1'[SType]) = "BB", CALCULATE(SUM('Table2'[MeanValue]), 'Table2'[S_type] = "BB"),
    SELECTEDVALUE('Table1'[SType]) = "CC", CALCULATE(SUM('Table2'[MeanValue]), 'Table2'[S_type] = "CC"),
    SELECTEDVALUE('Table1'[SType]) = "DD", CALCULATE(SUM('Table2'[MeanValue]), 'Table2'[S_type] = "DD"),
    BLANK()
)

